# SQL views and JSON disk caching

Tags: php, sql, json, caching, view

I'm programming a **reddit-like website**.

The user can display items from categories of its choice.

For this I'm querying a **JOIN** of the categories he subscribed to and the items.

Hardcore query

First solution : store the data on disk in a "**categories_1-2-4-7-10.json**" and serve it to the users browsing the same categories.

Cons : takes space on disk, **heavy load**.

I'm thinking about a new solution : **views**. But I don't really know how they work, do they regenerate often enough to be a heavyload on the server?

View would let me query data that already has been JOINED

Further : I'm only making a view for the frontpage items. I don't need to optimize later pages as they're not as frequently accessed.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea to store things to disk and then load them for a site. Disk operations are insanely slow compared to in memory operations.

You can still store JSON documents, but consider storing them in a caching layer.

Something like Redis, which is the new hotness these days (http://redis.io/) or Couchbase (http://www.couchbase.com/)

Store everything in memory and the site will be much faster.

As far as how often to regenerate your views ... a good idea is to give them an expiration time. Read about how that might work with caching in general. You would set a category view to exist in the cache for maybe 1 minute. After a minute the item leaves memory and you make a database query to put a newer version back in. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: From what I understand, Redis/Couchbase is basically memcached+SQL? You store your database in the memory?

Comment: Couchbase is built around Membase/Memcached.  Redis is something totally different.  You don't have to store your database in memory.  You can have a more traditional database on the back end, and Couch/Redis just store the results of queries - or the results of a service call.  Just helps you from having to run a live query against the database, which can be expensive.